Error handling in Flutter connecting to Supabase
I am just new to Flutter as well to Supabase and I'm wondering if there is a way to check if the database exist or it is connected during initialization like other PL or Scripting languages to connect to a database? References always show that this is the way to initialize Supabase connection:
Future<void> main() async {
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://xyzcompany.supabase.co',
    anonKey: 'public-anon-key',
  );

  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

It does not return any error message.  I have asked CoPilot about this and its solution is to create a simple request to know.
Future<void> main() async {
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'https://xyzcompany.supabase.co',
    anonKey: 'public-anon-key',
  );

  // Get a reference to your Supabase client
  final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

  // Make a simple request to the database
  final response = await supabase.from('your_table').select().limit(1).execute();

  // Check if the request was successful
  if (response.error != null) {
    print('Database is not accessible');
    print('Error: ${response.error.message}');
  } else {
    print('Database is accessible');
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}

Is this the only way? Or is there other way to inform the status of the connection.

You can check for any errors related to Supabase by wrapping your code with a standard try / catch block.

How will you wrap it with the try/catch block? What are the exceptions that it will catch?
